# Unable to display image over another image in div

Tags: css, html, image

```
<div id="back">
<div id="scale"></div>
<div id="pointer"></div>
</div>


CSS CODE :


#back
{width:99%;
height:100px;
position:relative;
}

#scale
{width:99%;
 height:100px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 background-image:url(Number_guessing_game/image/scale.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat
 }

 #pointer
 {width: 17px;
  height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image:url(Number_guessing_game/image/download.jpg);
  }
```

I am unable to display pointer image over scale image.
What should i do to display pointer image and pls tell 
what is the mistake in this?

Comment: a little google would have helped you

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `z-index` the one on top should have a higher value.

Comment: Could you explain me what is z index?